# Payload error in jsonwebtoken

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, jwt, passport.js

I am making a web application using nodejs and angular cli 
I'm using JWT to authenticate my login function . But when I process it threw this error

> Error: Expected "payload" to be a plain object.
>       at validate (D:\Mean_Projects\meanauthapp\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\sign.js:34:11)
>       at validatePayload (D:\Mean_Projects\meanauthapp\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\sign.js:56:10)
>       at Object.module.exports [as sign] (D:\Mean_Projects\meanauthapp\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\sign.js:108:7)
>       at User.comparePassword (D:\Mean_Projects\meanauthapp\routes\users.js:86:27)
>       at bcrypt.compare (D:\Mean_Projects\meanauthapp\models\user.js:53:9)
>       at D:\Mean_Projects\meanauthapp\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:297:21
>       at D:\Mean_Projects\meanauthapp\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:1353:21
>       at Immediate.next [as _onImmediate] (D:\Mean_Projects\meanauthapp\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:1233:21)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:785:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:747:5)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:718:5)

Here my passport code

```
    const JwtStrategy= require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
    const ExtractJwt=require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
    const User= require('../models/user');
    const config=require('../config/database');        
    module.exports=function(passport){
    let opts={};
    opts.jwtFromRequest=ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
    opts.secretOrKey=config.secret;
    opts.issuer = 'accounts.examplesoft.com';
    opts.audience = 'yoursite.net';
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts,(jwt_payload,done)=>{
        console.log(jwt_payload);
        User.getUserById(jwt_payload._doc._id,(err,user)=>{
            if(err){
                return done(err,false);
            }
            if(user){
                return done(null,user);
            }
            else{
                return done(null,false);
            }
        });
    }));
}
```

My code for authenticate and get profile

```
// Authenticate
router.post('/authenticate', (req, res, next) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;

  User.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(!user){
      return res.json({success: false, msg: 'User not found'});
    }

    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if(err) throw err;
      if(isMatch){
        const token = jwt.sign(user, config.secret, {
          expiresIn: 604800 // 1 week
        });

        res.json({
          success: true,
          token: 'JWT '+token,
          user: {
            id: user._id,
            name: user.name,
            username: user.username,
            email: user.email
          }
        });
      } else {
        return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Wrong password'});
      }
    });
  });
});

// Profile
router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({user: req.user});
});
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

It fails at the line

```
const token = jwt.sign(user, config.secret, {
```

With error *"Expected "payload" to be a plain object"*

Your `user` object is initialized here:

```
User.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user)
```

Which I assume is `mongoosejs` object, which contains many methods and is not "serializable". You could handle this by passing a plain object, by either using `.lean()` from `mongoose` or plain `toJSON` method:

```
const token = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), config.secret, {
  expiresIn: 604800 // 1 week
});
```

Comment: @T.Meyer please check the timing. Apparently my answer ( written in 2017 ) was copied by `sushil50889` to that `nodeauthapp` issue on github in 2018

Answer (score 22):

I had this problem as well, with a returned user from mongoose, just add `toJSON()` or `toObject()` will fix the issue, but what happens if your user is not always coming from mongoose?

You will get a

> user.toJson/user.ToObject is not a function

if you try to do this on a plain object.

If your user is coming from different sources and you don't know if it will be a plain object or not, you can solve it like this:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));
```

Comment: This seems to be the best answer

Comment: you can just do: `Object.assign({}, user)`. It's less wasteful

Comment: My answer directly solves the OPs issue with `mongoose`. I think there are better solutions for other cases, and serializing/deserializing JSONs is not optimal in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

this is clearly mentioned in the [migration doc of passport-jwt](https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt/blob/HEAD/docs/migrating.md)

that they have removed the `ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader()` from version 2 and 3 and also to use the new method `ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()` or one of like that in place of old method. for compelte reference [visit](https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt#extracting-the-jwt-from-the-request)

From your log there is the issue

```
User.comparePassword (D:\Mean_Projects\meanauthapp\routes\users.js:86:27) at
```

so here four thing need to be updated in your code `@every Bit`

First in package.json file 
Change the version to latest by using * or version no like this
by going to project directory and run the command

```
  npm install passport-jwt --save
    "dependencies": {
    ....     
        "passport-jwt": "^3.0.1"
      }
```

or 
write in the file and run the commadn

```
`npm install`
    "dependencies": {
        ....     
            "passport-jwt": "*"
          }
```

Second change this line of your code in authenticate method

```
const token = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), config.secret, {
  expiresIn: 604800 // 1 week
});
```

Third in the passport code change the old method

```
ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
```

to new one, from the doc reference you need to use this method `opts.jwtFromRequest=ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt');`

and fourth change this

```
User.getUserById(jwt_payload._id,(err,user)=>{
```

**This solution will work on latest version's**

---

- if you still want to use this old method then

---

**only change the version of your passport-jwt in package.json to 1.x.x (x is the nuber here )of your choise of lower version then 2**,
 by moving to project folder and runing the command `npm install`

the only thing you need to check is data in the payload_jwt,it will be inside the second layer so please check the jwt_payload.
ok you are all set to go you had already handled  `User.getUserById(jwt_payload._doc._id,(err,user)=>{`

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, if the user comes from database (mongo) then simply do `user.toJSON()`, if the user comes from any other source then simply do `JSON.stringify(user)`.

Answer (score 1):

if it's not comming from moongose 
then use **spread operator**

```
const token = jwt.sign({ ...payload }, config.secret, {
  expiresIn: 100080
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```
const token = jwt.sign(user, config.secret, { expiresIn: 10080 });
```

**To**

```
const token = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), config.secret, { expiresIn: 10080 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const token = jwt.sign(user, config.secret, {
      expiresIn: 604800 // 1 week
    });
```

convert this to

```
const token = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), config.secret, {
      expiresIn: 604800 // 1 week
    });
```

or you need to console.log(jwt_payload); to find your ID comes under _doc or directly with jwt_payload. because this may change with the versions.