# using jwt with passport get 404 error

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport-local

I try to create an authentification api with Express, Passport, Jwt, passport local, and Mariadb.
I don't need User model, but would like to use sql call.

I follow some tutorials : [tuto1](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/learn-using-jwt-with-passport-authentication-9761539c4314) [tuto2](https://jonathanmh.com/express-passport-json-web-token-jwt-authentication-beginners/) [tuto3](https://blog.jscrambler.com/implementing-jwt-using-passport/)
But I always get 404 error (POST request) with curl and postman.
I don't know where is the issue.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var logger = require('morgan');
var path = require('path');
var _ = require("lodash");
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var app = express();
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/routes')
var passport = require("passport");

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
next(err);
 });

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
// set locals, only providing error in development
res.locals.message = err.message;
res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

// render the error page
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.json({ error: err });
});

module.exports = app;
```

passport.js

```
var passport    = require('passport');
var passportJWT = require("passport-jwt");

var ExtractJWT = passportJWT.ExtractJwt;

var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var JWTStrategy   = passportJWT.Strategy;

var connection = require('./database');
var sodium = require('./sodium');

passport.use('local-signin', new LocalStrategy({
usernameField: 'username',
passwordField: 'password'
} , function (req, username, password, done){
  if(!username || !password ) {
    return done(null, false);
    }
  connection.query("select * from users where username = ?", [username], 
 function(err, rows){
      console.log(err);
      console.log(rows);
    if (err)
    return done(null, error);
    if(!rows.length){
      return done(null, false);
    }
    var dbpassword = rows[0].password;
    if(sodium.password_check(dbpassword, password) == false){
        return done(null, false);
     }
       return done(null, rows[0]);
   });
  })
);

passport.use(new JWTStrategy({
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    secretOrKey   : 'your_jwt_secret'
 },
 function (jwtPayload, cb) {
   connection.query("select * from users where id = ?", [jwtPayload.id], 
function(err, rows){
      console.log(err);
      console.log(rows);
    if (err)
    return done(null, error);
    if(!rows.length){
      return done(null, false);
    }
    var dbpassword = rows[0].password;
    if(sodium.password_check(dbpassword, password) == false){
        return done(null, false);
     }
       return done(null, rows[0]);
   });
  }
));

module.exports = passport ;
```

routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const jwt      = require('jsonwebtoken');
const passport = require('passport');

router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
passport.authenticate('local-signin', {session: false}, (err, user, info) => {
    if (err || !user) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            message: 'Something is not right',
            user   : user
        });
    }
   req.login(user, {session: false}, (err) => {
       if (err) {
           res.send(err);
       }
       const token = jwt.sign(user, 'my_secret');
       return res.json({user, token});
    });
     })
   (req, res);
 });

 module.exports = router ;
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: which route is not working?

Comment: It is on post route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

passport.use('local-signin',

passport.authenticate('local',

Could this inconsistency be an issue?

Comment: I must use this instead of `passport.use('local-signin', new LocalStrategy({ 
`?

Comment: No, try renaming passport.use('local-signin', to "local" and make the two same.

Comment: I change both to `local-signin` and have 404 error (I edit my post)

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry. Not really sure of the problem. Here is my implementation. express, passport.js, jwt, local strategy. May help (https://github.com/Tetsuya3850/MERN-Sprint/tree/master/auth/server)

Comment: Ok, thanks for sharing your repo. I refactoring my code, now, when I would like to sign token, I have this issue : `Expected "payload" to be a plain object`

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47117709/payload-error-in-jsonwebtoken) this?

Comment: Great ! Thanks :)

Comment: Oh great! if it all worked, please accept an answer! (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)